# How can I fix the "Error connecting with login URI" exception I get when adding events to Google Calendar?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I use the following code in Java. It works well and it adds events into Google Calendar. But in Android it gives the Exception `Error connecting with login URI`. Can anyone help me to solve this?

```
CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("calendarTest");
String userName = "mytest.test@gmail.com";
String userPassword = "xxxxxxx";

// Create the necessary URL objects.
try {
    metafeedUrl = new URL(METAFEED_URL_BASE + userName);
    eventFeedUrl = new URL(METAFEED_URL_BASE + userName
        + EVENT_FEED_URL_SUFFIX);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // Bad URL
    strbuf.append(e.getMessage());
    System.err.println("Uh oh - you've got an invalid URL.");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}

try
{
    myService.setUserCredentials(userName, userPassword);
    // Demonstrate creating a single-occurrence event.
    CalendarEventEntry singleEvent = createSingleEvent(myService,"Event Title", "Event Description "); 
    System.out.println("Successfully created event " +singleEvent.getTitle().getPlainText() );

    // Demonstrate creating a quick add event.
    CalendarEventEntry quickAddEvent = createQuickAddEvent(myService,"Tennis with me June 22 3pm-3:30pm");
    System.out.println("Successfully created quick add event "       + quickAddEvent.getTitle().getPlainText());

}
// catch.......
```

Comment: Please edit your question to have a better title.

Comment: purely style related, but why not have a single try/catch?  also, can you post the rest of the code.  finally, print the stacktrace, it frequently tells you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This needs internet-access to add something  to the calendar, right?

So you need to give your app the permission for internet access. Try adding this right before the closing tag of AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```