# how to solve this in android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix the “Error connecting with login URI” exception I get when adding events to Google Calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069757/how-can-i-fix-the-error-connecting-with-login-uri-exception-i-get-when-adding-e)

I am new to android. I can able to add the data to google calendar via my java application.But the same code is not working in the android.It gives the Exception message

**Error connecting with login URI**

how to solve this???

Comment: Dude... if you don't provide part of the code you are using, how could we help you? Anyway... just in case, have you add the `INTERNET` permission on the `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Answer (score 2):

In your AndroidManifest.xml file add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

But as Christian stated, without seeing any code what so ever, it is just a guess that this is your problem.

Also see "[How to solve this ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069757/how-to-solve-this)" that was posted about 30 minutes before yours, same issue.